# Volumetrics + Composition creates lots of noise in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, volumetrics

Why does my render look like this?[image]

What setting do I need to increase to solve this?

This started happening when I added the volumetrics. Here is my nodemap:[image]

And here are my render settings:
[image]
[image]

This is what my render looks like without the volumetrics. It's like I can't have both at once:[image]

Comment: So there is an object in the scene with a volumetric shader, right?

Comment: @Akshay2005 yes, just a principled volume

Comment: What does it give without the denoise?

Comment: @moonboots no different from the first image